# Can someone explain why this bug happens on my navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you look closely, when you scroll down fast, the navbar turns black for a split second before it disappears. How do I prevent this bug from happening?

What I am trying to do with the navbar:
1. The navbar is supposed to become transparent at the top of the page except for the text inside the navbar.
2.when you scroll down the page the navbar should disappear fully, the text should also disappear
3. when you scroll up in the bottom part of the page, the navbar should reappear with a black background.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Transition effect for navbar 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          // checks if window is scrolled more than 500px, adds/removes solid class
          if($(this).scrollTop() > 500) { 
              $('.header').addClass('solid');
          } else {
              $('.header').removeClass('solid');
          }
        });

  
});

var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = 505;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 350);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    
   
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').addClass('no-bar').removeClass('solid');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('no-bar');
        }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
/************************************************HEADER*********************************************************/
 
body {
 height:500%;
 padding-bottom: 500%;
 background: green;
}

 .header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw
  padding-top: 6%;
  padding-bottom: 6%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  padding-right: 100vw;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 324;
  border-bottom: 0%;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
 }

 .solid {
  background-color: black;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px grey;
 }

 .no-bar {
 opacity: 0;
 }

  .logo {
    color: yellow;
    position: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    padding: 0;
    left: 37%;
  }



  .nav-fade {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

    .section-1 {
  position: relative;
  top:80%;
  padding-top: 6%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  height: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
 }

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="STACK-HEADER.CSS">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
   <div class="logo">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
   </div>
  </header>
   <section class="section-1">
     </section>


  <section class="section-1">
     </section>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="STACK-HEADER.JS"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

. How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have merged two conditions in a if:

```
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').addClass('no-bar').removeClass('solid');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('no-bar');
        }
    }
```

`t > lastScrollTop` means we're going down otherwise we're assuming we're going up.
If we're going up the solid class is added.
But since you've merged `t > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight` it now means that we're assuming to go up whenever `st <= navbarHeight`.

Therefore the solid bar is showing when we scroll down near the top.

You just have to rewrite this piece of code like this:

```
    if (st > lastScrollTop){
            // Scroll Down
            if (st > navbarHeight) {
                $('header').addClass('no-bar').removeClass('solid');
            }
        } else {
            // Scroll Up
            if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                $('header').removeClass('no-bar');
            }
        }
```

Be careful with `else`!

Working snippet below:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
            // Transition effect for navbar 
            $(window).scroll(function() {
              // checks if window is scrolled more than 500px,
              // adds/removes solid class
              if($(this).scrollTop() > 500) { 
                  $('.header').addClass('solid');
              } else {
                  $('.header').removeClass('solid');
              }
            });

      
    });

    var didScroll;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var delta = 5;
    var navbarHeight = 505;

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        didScroll = true;
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        if (didScroll) {
            hasScrolled();
            didScroll = false;
        }
    }, 350);

    function hasScrolled() {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        
        
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
            return;
        
       
        if (st > lastScrollTop){
            // Scroll Down
            if (st > navbarHeight) {
                $('header').addClass('no-bar').removeClass('solid');
            }
        } else {
            // Scroll Up
            if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                $('header').removeClass('no-bar');
            }
        }
        
        lastScrollTop = st;
    }
```

```css
    
 
    /************************HEADER*********************************/
     
    body {
     height:500%;
     padding-bottom: 500%;
     background: green;
    }

     .header {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100vw
      padding-top: 6%;
      padding-bottom: 6%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0%;
      left: 0%;
      padding-right: 100vw;
      transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
      z-index: 324;
      border-bottom: 0%;
      background-color: transparent;
      transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
     }

     .solid {
      background-color: black;
      transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
      box-shadow: 0 0 4px grey;
     }

     .no-bar {
     opacity: 0;
     }

      .logo {
        color: yellow;
        position: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 38%;
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding: 0;
        left: 37%;
      }



      .nav-fade {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }

        .section-1 {
      position: relative;
      top:80%;
      padding-top: 6%;
      padding-bottom: 50%;
      height: 200%;
      width: 100%;
      background: green;
     }

      }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="STACK-HEADER.CSS">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
    </head>

    <body>
      <header class="header">
       <div class="logo">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
       </div>
      </header>
       <section class="section-1">
         </section>


      <section class="section-1">
         </section>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="STACK-HEADER.JS"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "1. The navbar is supposed to become transparent at the top of the page except for the text inside the navbar." => this is true
"2. when you scroll down the page the navbar should disappear fully, the text should also disappear" => this is true
"3. when you scroll up in the bottom part of the page, the navbar should reappear with a black background." => this is unclear but partially true.
What the part not working for you?

Comment: When I scroll down quickly in the top part of the page, the navbar turns black again for a split second before it disappears.